# Flutter Spotlight Carousel obtener el index actual

Tags: flutter, dart, carrusel

estoy implementando un carousel de tipo spotlight y no hallo la forma de obtener el indice actual del carrusel para redirigir a otro screen
El código del widget es:

```
body:Container(
            height:650,
            color: Colors.orange[50],

            child: SpotlightCarousel(
              minSize: Size.square(50.0),
              maxSize: Size.square(150.0),
              images: images,
              titles: texts,
              descriptions: descriptions,
              pageIndicatorColor: Colors.black,
              showPageIndicator: true,

            ),
          )
      ),
```

Sería una solución, según creo, revisar el contenido del widget para buscar un string, pero no sé cómo implementarlo.
Gracias.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, veo que ese package tiene un atributo llamado `ScrollController controller`, puedes sacar provecho de este.

Si revisas el código, tiene una validación , si `_controller is PageController` entonces usa un `PageView.builder`.

Quedaría así:

```dart
final PageController controller = PageController();

//En initState, escucha ese controller
controller.addListener((){
     //aquí tienes en que página se encuentra
      print("Controller current page: ${controller.page}");
    });

//En dispose, libera el controller
 controller.dispose();

//Finalmente asígnale a tu carousel

SpotlightCarousel(
              minSize: Size.square(50.0),
              maxSize: Size.square(150.0),
              images: images,
              titles: texts,
              descriptions: descriptions,
              pageIndicatorColor: Colors.black,
              showPageIndicator: true,
              controller: controller,
            ),
```

Mas info sobre **PageController** : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController-class.html

Comment: Estimado Diego, como siempre !!! muchas gracias! Funcionó a la perfección!